# Jquery Jqui Modal Window: opening same modal multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, increment, jqui

I'm working on a javascript function that opens a jquery modal window and makes an ajax call to populate the modal.  I've included 'left' and 'right' div ids- clicking one changes the content of the modal window (scrolling through a photo slideshow).

Everything works great, except one thing: If I open the modal and then close it, opening it a 2nd time causes these 'left/right' buttons to count each click as two (click 'right' once, but move two images over).  If I close the window and reopen it again, the counting again increases by 1 (3 changes for 1 click).

The only workaround that fixes this is to reload the page when the modal window is closed- but does anyone know of a better solution?  Basically, I want to 'reset' the modal window, but don't want to destroy it- I'd like to be able to open/close the modal multiple times and have these right/left buttons work.

The part of the function that I've used to create these buttons is below- thanks for any suggestions/ideas.

```
    function getNextImage(direction) {
        if(direction == 1) {
            if(imageNumber == 1) {
                    imageNumber = lastImage;
                } else {
                    --imageNumber;
                }
            }
        if(direction == 2) {
            if(imageNumber == lastImage) {
                    imageNumber = 1;
                } else {
                    ++imageNumber;
                }
            }
        if(direction == 0) {
            imageNumber = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "phpIncludes/next_fetch.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {img : imageNumber, cap : imageNumber, width : dWidth, height : dHeight, a : album},
            success: function(htmlpic) {
                $("#left"+album).html(htmlpic);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#moveLeft"+album).click(function() {
        getNextImage(1);
        console.log("Image Number is: " + imageNumber);
    });

    $("#moveRight"+album).click(function() {
        getNextImage(2)
        console.log("Image Number is: " + imageNumber);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in this part::

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "phpIncludes/next_fetch.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {img : imageNumber, cap : imageNumber, width : dWidth, height : dHeight, a : album},
            success: function(htmlpic) {
                $("#left"+album).html(htmlpic);
            }
        });

before your add the htmlpic to the #left , proib first put empty this content #left and verify if its done !!

Comment: Thanks for the good idea!  Unfortunately, I tried it, but it didn't work.  The left/right buttons still gain the '+1' increment if the modal's closed, then reopened.